# Successive quotients of powers of a non-zero prime ideal in Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, and $P$ a non-zero proper prime ideal of $R$. It is easy to show that we have proper descending chain of ideals 
$$R \supset P \supset P^2 \supset P^3\cdots$$
Also $R/P$ is a field, and so $P^k/P^{k+1}$ becomes module over $R/P$ i.e. vector space over field $R/P$.

> **Claim:** $P^k/P^{k+1}$ is one dimensional vector space over $R/P$.
>
> **Proof:** Consider $\pi\in P^k\setminus P^{k+1}$. Then $R\pi\subseteq P^k$ but $R\pi\nsubseteq P^{k+1}$. Thus, $R\pi$ factors into prime ideals as 
>   $R\pi=P^kQ_1\cdots Q_r$ where $Q_i$ are prime ideals different from $P$. Then 
>   $$R\pi+P^{k+1}=P^kQ_1\cdots Q_r + P^{k+1}=P^k(Q_1\cdots Q_r+P)=P^kR=P^k$$
>   where we used in last-but-second equality that $Q_1\cdots Q_r+P$ contains $P$ properly (easy to show) and hence is equal to $R$.
>
> Thus $(R\pi+P^{k+1})/P^{k+1}=P^k/P^{k+1}$. [**Next?**]

**Q.** From this last equation, how can we conclude that $P^k/P^{k+1}$ is of dimension $1$?

---

In the book Basic Algebra by Knapp, I confused in similar arguments at the point above, there was some typo; see [here, page 442](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/download/b2-alg-inside.pdf).

Comment: It's generated by the single element $\pi$.

Comment: Can we say this: $R\pi+P^{k+1}=P^k$, thus,the coset space $P^k/P^{k+1}$ is scalar multiple of single coset $\pi+P^{k+1}$, hence one-dimensional.

Comment: $R/P$ isn’t a field. You need to take $P$ maximal (or assume $R$ of dimension $1$).

Comment: @Mindlack: Sorry; extremely sorry; this came up from section on Dedekind domain in Knapp's book, but I forgot to write it when typing question.